# CSS <div> is not extending down the entire page

Tags: html, css, dynamic, expand

I'm trying to get a `.page` in CSS to extend down to the end of the page. And not the end of the screen, but to where the information on an HTML page ends. How would I do this? My current config for .page is:

```css
.page{
  width: 800px;
  height: 550px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: #FCFCFA;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

How would I achieve this. I have several pages using this, and they're not all the same length, so I would like to have this dynamically adjust. If this helps the information is `#main1` and `.sideright`. if there is any other information that I need to post I will happily post it.

HTML: http://pastebin.com/1MZt1as4
Second Page: http://pastebin.com/CCDFe9B3
CSS: http://pastebin.com/BSLDjc4D

Comment: Could you provide a link to your code/site or a jsfiddle?

Comment: can you add a fiddle or codepen? http://jsfiddle.net/ http://codepen.io/

Comment: This isn't very clear if you don't let us see how to page looks. For all we know #main1 and .sideright could be positioned in any way at all.

Comment: @jezzipin added the links to the code.

Comment: @Yvette Yeah it's good and briefly described here: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

```css
html {

    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;

    height: 100%;
}
div.container {

    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Your code:

```css
html{
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    background-image:url('../Pictures/Background.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:#AEAEAE;
    font-family: Verdana;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You had a back tick at height: 100% in body

//how far do you want these .page and .pageout to extend? You have specified heights. If you want them to extend the full length of the page you need to set the heights to

```
min-height: 100%;
```

//===================

```css
.page{
    width: 800px;
    height: 550px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #FCFCFA;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.pageout{
    width: 810px;
    height: 555px;
    margin: 0px auto;

    background: #C0CACF
}
```

Comment: That got rid of all the CSS background completely, except for my background gradient.

Comment: What do you mean how far do you want these .page and .pageout to extend? are you talking about how the border is?

Comment: I had the specified heights because something broke before that made it dynamically expand, so the only way to make it work was to make specified heights. I was hoping that I could remove them or somehow make them be dynamic

Comment: found this **[useful article](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/anyorder.html)** (+[test](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/M2MBc/))

Answer (score -1):

If you want `.page` to take height of parent(s) element, than the parent(s) must have height too. Setting height to `100%` would mean nothing if parent element has no height.

Offtopic, but probably helpful for you:
From my experience, the only thing you would need height for is (I guess) setting the background color. Solution: set the bg-color or image slice to some of parent elements that occupy the area of your `.page` element.